# Run maven spi projects to debug

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, spi

There is a pretty cool example of a spi architecture with maven at baeldung:

Tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/java-spi

Repository: https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/java-spi

It has a parent pom and three child poms. To run the application I have first to build it by maven. Then I have run the build jars in terminal.

How can I run it without the usage of jars and terminal so I can debug the app and service provider it in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create run configuration for `com.baeldung.rate.app.MainApp`. Add there VM argument

`-Djava.ext.dirs=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext:./exchange-rate-impl/target:./exchange-rate-impl/target/depends`

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried it but the service loader does not find any service.

Comment: Try to use absolute path to both irectories: `exchange-rate-impl/target` and `exchange-rate-impl/target/depends`

Comment: If you are satisfied with answer mark it as correct and upvote it. Stackoverflow is driven by this.

Comment: i marked it as correct but i cant upvote because i have not enough reputation for doing it